# WPF Resolution Emulation

Tags: wpf, dynamic, user-interface, screen-resolution

We have a WPF system in which we are allowing our clients to design a UI interface for their users. One of the main issues we have is that our clients will possibly be designing an interface in one resolution (ie. 1366x768) to be deployed to a system in another (ie. 1024x768). We've come up with our own solution but always seem to run into issues regarding overlapping elements, size differences, etc. I'm posting this question to query the Stack Overflow masses on possible ideas they may have regarding emulating one resolution within another (ie. giving a preview of a ui for a 1024x768 resolution on a screen with a 1366x768 resolution). Please feel free to get the creative juices flowing and post suggestions.

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm not getting your problem.
Can't you just set your window size according to what you want to test ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping the parent container in a ViewBox and set the height and width of the ViewBox to 1024x768 or 1366x768 and see if that resizes the children correctly.

Comment: Thats how I would do it, grid inside the viewbox, you can set the width and height of the grid to the screen resolution you want to emulate and then it doesn't matter what size the viewbox is, you will need to set the scale mode to maintain aspect ratio.